# how to validate the below criteria on the text fields and display the pop up page on satisfying all the condition using javascript validation

Tags: javascript

```
   **Below is the input text fileds**

<form:form commandName="DRCNdetails"  id="frm1" method="POST" action="addNewDelayReason.do" >
       <form:input id="text1" path="delayCategory" cssClass="padR10 boxSizing"   maxlength="75"></form:input>
      <form:input path="preFix"  id="text2" cssClass="padR10 boxSizing" maxlength="6">            </form:input>
         <form:input path="reasonValue" maxlength="150" id="reasonValue"    cssClass="textbox width100" cssStyle="visibility:hidden"></form:input>
                  </form:form> <button class="btnStyle blueBtn"                         onclick="formvalidation(),validateSpecialCharacters()"> <span class="left">
```

Submit

on submit  need to vaidate the id's "text1","text2" fileds , on successful validation           should display the below pop up screen that is showLtBox('mask', 'addMisdReasonCode1'), the                              conditions are below:

```
             should not allow the null values for both the fileds, and special characters,and integers  and alert me accordingly , on satisying this criteria only it should display the pop up screen showLtBox('mask', 'addMisdReasonCode1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript Regular expression..

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]{n}$/);
```

where `n` is number of charecters you want to accept.

the above regular expression matches only charecters(both cases).

Now retrieve the value from your `text fields`

```
var text1 = document.getElementById("#your_id").value;
var text2 = document.getElementById("#your_id").value;

if(pattern.test(text1) && pattern.test(text2))
{
// your popup code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question, you need to create a validation function that would be triggered upon pressing the submit button.

I already see that you have created to function that would be triggered on "OnClick" operation, However the syntax is incorrect.

1. You need to separate between the two function using ";" and not ","
2. You need to use only one function for validation - this would be more readable than the code you have written.
3. The result should be returned to the onclick command.

Example:
change the attribute onclick as follows:

```
onclick="return FullValidation();"
```

Create new JavaScript function that includes the two validations and return validation result;

```
function FullValidation() {
 var validationResultOK = formvalidation();
 if (validationResultOK) {
    validationResultOK  = validateSpecialCharacters();
 }
 if (validationResultOK) {
  // Popup alert should be here, I put alert as example.
  alert("Out your message here");
 }
 return validationResultOK;
}
```